# Figuring out if a word is followed by a space or newline

Tags: c++

Current Code:

```
void LinkedList::readFunct( string file ) {
string word;
string trailing_char;
stringstream ss;

ifstream infile ( file.c_str() );
while ( getline( infile, word)) {
    cout << "The line is " << word << endl;
    ss << word;
    while ( getline ( ss, word, ' ' )) {
        trailing_char = "space";
        cout << "Word: " << word << endl << "Trail: "<< trailing_char << endl;
    }
    ss.str( string() );
    ss.clear();
}
}
```

The code attempts to pull from a text file (The name of which is passed to it), read through it, find the words (separated by either a space or a newline character) and then figure out the trailing character (The mentioned space or newline)

so a textfile like:

```
abc def ghi

jkl mno pqr
```

should have abc followed by a space, ghi and pqr followed by a new line ( I know in reality it wouldn't but I'm assigning everything to a linked list for later futzing with and Ill need to know that was the end of the line).

I've tried to figure this puzzle out for hours and Im at wits end. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first read the string using `std::getline(in, word)` which will eat up all the newlines. When you then use `std::getline(in, word, ' ')` the last word may be immediately followed by nothing, i.e., it was at a line boundary. The way you could check for the difference between a newline and a space is to check if the inner `std::getline()` stopped because of a space or because it reached the end of the string in which case it stopped, effectively, because the following character was a newline:

```
while (std::getline( infile, word)) {
    std::cout << "The line is '" << word << "'\n";
    ss.clear();
    ss.str(word);
    while (std::getline (ss, word, ' ' )) {
        trailing_char = ss.eof()? "newline": "space";
        cout << "Word: " << word << endl << "Trail: "<< trailing_char << '\n';
    }
}
```

A somewhat easier method would be to just read the file one word at a time and print whether the character following a word is present, a space, or a newline (or one of the other whitespace characters for that matter):

```
for (std::string word; infile >> word; ) {
    switch (infile.peek()) {
    case '\n': trail = "newline"; break;
    case '\r': trail = "carriage-return"; break;
    case ' ': trail = "space"; break;
    case '\f\: trail = "form-feed"; break;
    // ...?
    default: trail = "end-of-file"; break;
    }
    std::cout << "word='" << word << "' trail=" << trail << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I have never actually seen the peek function. Ill need to read up on that. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `getline` by default separates by newlines, so this should be all you need. Example:

```
std::ifstream infile("text.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    bool firstword = true;
    for (std::string word; iss >> word; )
    {
        if (!firstword) { std::cout << "SPACE\n"; }
        std::cout << word;
        firstword = false;
    }
    std::cout << "NEWLINE\n";
}
```

The complication with the boolean flag is because you have one less space than you have words.

Comment: I am an idiot. I never thought to use a for loop. I guess this is my punishment for not sleeping :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code:

```
void LinkedList::readFunct( string file ) {
string word;
string trailing_char;
stringstream ss;

ifstream infile ( file.c_str() );
while ( getline( infile, word)) {
    cout << "The line is " << word << endl;
    ss << word;
    bool firsttime = true;
    while ( ss >> word ) {
        if (!firsttime)
             cout << "Trail: space" << endl;
        cout << "Word: " << word << endl;
        firsttime = false;
    }
    if (!firsttime)
         cout << "Trail: NEWLINE" << endl;
    else
         cout << "empty line." << endl;
    ss.str( string() );
    ss.clear();
}
}
```